# Data access Spark EC2

Tags: scala, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

After following instruction to install cluster via ec2 script, i'm not able to correctly launch my .jar because they don't find the data file which i put on /root/persistent-hdfs/ on the master and slave nodes.
I read on an other post that i need to prefix the file location with file:// but it doesn't change anything... I have this error :

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file://root/persistent-hdfs/data/ds_1.csv

To launch the job i used the ./bin/spark-submit on the master node, am i correct ?

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: please post the full command you are suing to submit the job. Also post your job code.

Comment: I used this command :
spark_submit --class "MS1" MS1.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do:

1. The default configuration uses the ephemeral hdfs so you need to turn that off `$ /root/ephemeral-hdfs/bin/stop-all.sh` and turn persistent on `$ /root/persistent-hdfs/bin/start-all.sh`.
2. Put your file into the persistent hdfs root directory for simplicity `$ /root/persistent-hdfs/bin/hadoop fs -put /root/ds_1.csv /ds_1.csv`. Now check to see it is actually there `$ /root/persistent-hdfs/bin/hadoop fs -ls`.
3. Finally, edit Spark's configuration files in `/root/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf` and `/root/spark/conf/spark-env.sh` and change everything that says ephemeral to persistent.

Assuming you put your csv in the root directory of the persistent hdfs (as we did in step 2) you can access it in spark using `val rawData = sc.textFile("/ds_1.csv")`.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you very much, i'm trying right now.
Do i make this steps on master and slaves, or just on master ?

Comment: Thank you, scripts are on sbin and not into bin. When i check if the file is in the hdfs it respond me that there's nothing but when i recall the `hdfs/bin/hadoop fs -put /root/ds_1.csv /ds_1.csv `  it says  `put:/ds_1.csv': File exists`.
I have this error when i run the job 
`Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Call From ip-172-31-48-78.ec2.internal/172.31.48.78 to ec2-52-4-114-103.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connexion refusée; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused`

Comment: You need to open port 9000 on your master and slaves via the ec2 security groups for master and slaves and repeat the put command.

Comment: I did both things :
First i open UDP/TCP port 9000 on aws security group
Second i used this functions : `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 9000 --syn -j ACCEPT`
`iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT`
Both of this things on master and slaves and i have the same error.

Comment: Result is the same, i remove the file with `hadoop fs -rm` et put de file and the error is still here...
I even try to authorize all the traffic on aws ec2 groups, same results....

Comment: What is the output of ```$ /root/persistent-hdfs/bin/hadoop fs -ls```?

Comment: @KyBe Turns out there are two configuration files you need to edit (see the updated answer). Also the start-all.sh and stop-all.sh scripts are indeed in bin, not sbin. I've just confirmed these instructions work.

Comment: The error about the port 9000 is coming back with spark-1.4, i don't know if it's me or another trick to append to the list of things to do.
The hadoop fs -ls / show me the file.
I open all trafic in slave and master security group but nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the code of your job would provide more details.

So far looks like workers cannot access the file on the local file system of the driver.
You need to use hadoop fs -put or -cp command to upload your file to HDFS. So workers will be able access the file with hdfs:// uri.

Since you are running your cluster on EC2 I would suggest to put the file to s3 bucket and use s3://... file uri.